# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload redirect

Tags: java, redirect, blueimp

I am using the blueimp  jQuery-File-Upload on SpringSource Tool Suite 2.9.1.

1. I am trying to redirect from my UploadServlet , but because the option redirect is already 
   defined (on main.js) it create an error.
   how can I redirect from my UploadServlet.java , after the files are uploaded .
2. In the example code they redirect to results.html , When I try this it upload the files but 
   after doPost function finish (in my UploadServlet.java) nothing happens & It doesn't
   redirect .

please help me and give me an example how to do those thing .

Thanks

Tami

Answer (score 0):

I've been through a similar issue when using the plugin on Google App Engine. [Here is the complete working code](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Google-App-Engine-Java). May be you'll have slight differences, but I guess you'll find how a Java server have to be done for this plugin to work.